# How to "grep" a rpm?

Tags: rpm

Find a file provides by rpm is easy

```
dnf provides *bin/vim
```

or

```
yum whatprovides *bin/vim
```

If you have rpm installed or yum..but suppose I want to know the content of rpm for exact file.
For example

```
grep -ril bin/vim v*
vim-9.0.1572-1.2.ppc64.rpm
```

Too easy

but I want to know the EXACT package which contain bin/sh, how to do?
Using this return the packages which have bin/sh also as a depend.
I want to know the exact package which provides bin/sh as a file.

```
grep -ril bin/sh v*
v4l-conf-3.107-2.10.ppc64.rpm
vacation-1.2.7.1-13.3.ppc64.rpm
vim-9.0.1572-1.2.ppc64.rpm
virt-what-1.25-1.2.ppc64.rpm
vpnc-0.5.3r550-3.12.ppc64.rpm
vsftpd-3.0.5-10.1.ppc64.rpm
```

Comment: On a debian system you can install and use `apt-file` to get that info. I have no idea if there's a way on rpm-based systems.

Comment: @Henriksupportsthecommunity One of the methods for this on distros that use `rpm` such as Fedora and derivatives is in the question and in my answer. `yum provides /path/to/file` which can also be used with wildcards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rpm -qf` will tell you what package owns a file.

e.g.

```
% rpm -qf /bin/sh
bash-4.2.46-35.el7_9.x86_64

% rpm -qf /bin/vim
vim-enhanced-7.4.629-8.el7_9.x86_64
```

If a package isn't installed, then you can see the contents with `rpm -qlp`  e.g

```
% rpm -qlp binutils-2.27-44.base.el7.x86_64.rpm | head
/usr/bin/addr2line
/usr/bin/ar
/usr/bin/as
/usr/bin/c++filt
/usr/bin/dwp
/usr/bin/elfedit
/usr/bin/gprof
/usr/bin/ld
/usr/bin/ld.bfd
/usr/bin/ld.gold
```

From that it would be simple to create an "index" file of the contents of all the rpms in a directory, and then just grep that index.

An off the top of my head example:

```
% for a in *.rpm
do
  rpm -qlp "$a" | sed "s/^/$a:/"
done > index

% grep :/usr/bin/sh index
bash-4.2.46-34.el7.x86_64.rpm:/usr/bin/sh
```

Note I had to search for /usr/bin/sh because /bin is a symlink to /usr/bin

Comment: FTR, would be equivalent to Debian's `dpkg -S`/`--search`, very useful with `$(which command)`

Comment: Thanks, but probably explain bad my request. I already know how to know which package own the file, my request is which package own the file if not installed, for example I'm on Slackware, I want to know which package rpm contain the exact line "/bin/sh". How to do?

Answer (score 1):

The very first command in your question with any variation of `*bin/<file>` gives exactly what you are asking for:

```
yum provides *bin/vim

yum provides /bin/vim

yum provides /usr/bin/vim

vim-enhanced-2:8.2.2637-20.el9_1.x86_64 : A version of the VIM editor which includes recent enhancements
Repo        : @System
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/bin/vim

vim-enhanced-2:8.2.2637-20.el9_1.x86_64 : A version of the VIM editor which includes recent enhancements
Repo        : appstream
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/bin/vim
```

`yum` can be swapped for `dnf`. That returns the package whether it is installed or not.

If it's for a file contained by a package that is actually installed:

```
rpm -qf /bin/sh
bash-5.1.8-6.el9_1.x86_64

rpm -qf /usr/bin/vim
vim-enhanced-8.2.2637-20.el9_1.x86_64
```

Comment: Thanks, but probably explain bad my request. I already know how to know which package own the file, my request is which package own the file if not installed, for example I'm on Slackware, I want to know which package rpm contain the exact line "/bin/sh". How to do?

Comment: @elbarna  Slackware doesn't use `rpm` for its packages. There is no way to return a line containing only `/bin/sh` for a package that isn't installed in a distro that uses `rpm` unless you pipe `yum provides /bin/sh` into a tool like `sed` or `awk`. If that doesn't explain it, then you'll need to edit your question to show exactly what you want.

Comment: I know Slackware don't use rpm (it use tgz or txz format), but has rpm command. If no way to know line of rpm not installed, add your comment as answer so I can close the question.